# Session's user id not present

Tags: next.js

I am a newbie in the nextjs world. I want to implement next-auth, and so far ive done so successfully with credentials provider, but when using useSession(), the user has only name and email.

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({

      name: "Credentials",

      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const user = await AuthService.getUserByEmail(credentials?.email!);

        return {
          id: user._id.toString(),
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.sub;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

//and page.tsx
"use client";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";


export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(session);
```